# Show that the following holds $\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln x}{(x^3)}dx=-\int_0^1x\ln x\ dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Without evaluating the integrals show that: $$\displaystyle\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln x}{(x^3)}dx=-\int_0^1x\ln x\ dx$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit immediately hints $\displaystyle x=\frac1y,dx=-\frac{dy}{y^2}\implies \ln x=\ln\frac1y=\ln(y)^{-1}=-\ln y$

$$\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln x}{x^3}\ dx=\int_1^0 y^3\cdot(-\ln y)\cdot\left(-\frac{dy}{y^2}\right)=\cdots$$

Can you take it home from here?

Comment: Yeah thanks that's great, I'd never come across this method of x=1/y before.